# Perform an intermediate action and carry over the previous result in bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Is there a shorthand which would allow to get the value of the Promise and push it forward the promise chain without explicitly returning it?

In other words, is there a shorthand syntax for the following in bluebird:

```
.then(result => { callSomething(result); return result })
```

Comment: You have to return it but with short and inline arrow functions i prefer the comma operator like `.then(v => (doSomething(v),v))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your going to use this pattern often, why not make a generic method for it

```
Promise.prototype.skip = function skip(fn, onRejected) {
    return this.then(value => Promise.resolve(fn(value)).then(() => value), onRejected);
};
```

Let's say your example `callSomething` returns a promise

```
function callSomething(v) {
    console.log('skip got', v);
    // this promise will be waited for, but the value will be ignored
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'wilma'));
}
```

now, b using `skip`, instead of `then`, the incoming fulfilled value, in this case `fred`, will just pass on the following `then`, but AFTER the promise returned by `callSomething` is fulfilled

```
Promise.resolve('fred').skip(callSomething).then(console.log); // outputs "fred"
```

However, it doesn't matter if `callsomething` doesn't return a Promise

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) inside your arrow function's body (without curly braces):

```
.then(result => (callSomething(result), result)
```

The comma operator

> evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

So, `result` is returned by expression:

```
(callSomething(result), result)
```

Then, the arrow function without curly braces, returns the value of the expression specified as its body. For this reason, `result` is returned.

Comment: `So you have always return the value of a promise in the onFulfilled and onRejected callbacks to propagate the value down the chain` your statement implies that `onFulfilled` must return a promise - at least that is how I inferred it, I may be alone in that inference. It's `.then` that must return a promise, not its callbacks - though they **can** return a promise, of course

Comment: You are correct @JaromandaX: it's `.then` that *must* return a promise, not its callback which can return also simple values. I removed that part from my answer because was incorrect and not very much pertinent. Thank you.